# Parameterize ORM query with where in clause

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

I'm trying to parametrize a query that is currently working and is ripe for an SQL injection attack:

```
qryAwards = ORMExecuteQuery(
    "from Award where awardID in (#form.deleteAwardList#) and Game.Season.User.userID=:uid",
    {uid=session.userID}
);
if(not isNull(qryAwards) and arrayLen(qryAwards)){
    for(i in qryAwards){
        entityDelete(i);
    }
}
```

I tried this, having the param without single quotes:

```
qryAwards = ORMExecuteQuery(
    "from Award where awardID in (:awardList) and Game.Season.User.userID=:uid",
    {awardList=form.deleteAwardList, uid=session.userID}
);
```

I keep getting the following error:

`The value 117,118 cannot be converted to a number.`

And this, with the param enclosed in single quotes:

```
qryAwards = ORMExecuteQuery(
    "from Award where awardID in (':awardList') and Game.Season.User.userID=:uid",
    {awardList=form.deleteAwardList, uid=session.userID}
);
```

Gets me the following error:

`Invalid parameters specified for the query.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In HQL (which is what you use when you do `ORMExecuteQuery()` ) parameters used in an `IN` clause need to be passed as an array. You need to convert `form.deleteAwardList` to an array. There are a few different ways to handle this, but this will work.

```
qryAwards = ORMExecuteQuery(
    "from Award where awardID in (:awardList) and Game.Season.User.userID=:uid",
    {awardList=listToArray( form.deleteAwardList ), uid=session.userID}
);
```

Comment: Out of idle curiosity, does this approach escape apostrophes?

Comment: It should. Anytime you parameterize data like this special characters are escaped, just like in `cfparam`. Also, you can't use `cfqueryparam` wtih `ORMExecuteQuery()`. By using parameters the way he is, it is the same as using `cfqueryparam`